# counting occurrences of patterns in data frame columns by groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl, summarize

I have a data frame that contains one column with strings coding events and one column with participant numbers. Every participant has multiple rows of events. Event codes contain keywords separated by underscores. I would like to count the occurrence of specific keywords per participant and put this in a new dataframe with one row per participant.

I have tried to do this by using grepl to find the keywords and then group_by and summarise to create a new data frame. Here is a minimal example:

```
part = rep(1:5,4)
events = c("black_white","black_blue","black_yellow","black_white","black_blue","black_yellow","black_white","black_blue","black_yellow","black_white","black_blue","black_yellow","black_white","black_blue","black_yellow","black_white","black_blue","black_yellow","black_white","black_blue")
data = data.frame(part,events)

data_sum = data %>%
  group_by(part) %>%
  summarise(
    black = sum(grepl("black",data$event)),
    black_yellow = sum(grepl("black_yellow",data$event))
  )
```

However, if I run this, the counts are not grouped by participant but the overall counts, therefore, the same for everyone.

Does anyone have any tipps on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove tha `data$`, `sum(grepl("black", event))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
data_sum = data %>%
  group_by(part) %>%
  summarise(
    black = sum(grepl("black",events)),
    black_yellow = sum(grepl("black_yellow",events))
  )
```